# recursively find a file in a given path in reverse order

Tags: bash

Team,

I have a given path `src/services/team`

I want to find a file `BAZEL.build` in this entire path in reverse order and stop as soon as it is found in reverse order. that is first search in `src/services/team` then `src/services/` then  `src/` and if found in first `src/services/team` dont search further but just save the found path in a var. also, i used a while loop to stop recursive search if we reached the first dir that is `src`. I don't want to search in forward way but rather start from backward dir in a given path.

so I tried this but am unable to come up with logic to populate npath.

```
apath="src/services/team"
root_dir="src"
recursive_find_bazel_file_in_apath(){
    bbf="BUILD.bazel"
    if [ -f "$apath/$bbf" ]; then
        bazel_cov_req+=(//$apath)
     else
        while(npath != "${root_dir}") #stop searching if all dirs in reverse order are done and we are src.
        do
            echo "find in path one up"
            cd "$apath" && cd ../
            npath="some_logic_to_store src/services, i am struggling on how to do this"
            if [ -f "$npath/$bbf" ]; then
            bazel_cov_req+=(//$npath)
         done
      fi
}
```

Comment: Note that there are *many* traps and pitfalls associated with using `cd` in shell programs.  It's best to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in your function body:

```
npath=$apath
bbf_path=''
while [[ -n $npath ]]; do
    if [[ -f $npath/$bbf ]]; then
        bbf_path=$npath/$bbf
        break
    fi
    [[ $npath == */* ]] && npath=${npath%/*} || npath=''
done
```

- `bbf_path` is set to the path to the lowest directory containing a `$bbf` file.  It is left empty if no such file is found.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${npath%/*}`.
- The `break` stops the loop as soon as one `$bbf` file is found.
- The code uses Bashisms so make sure that the file containing it has a `#! /bin/bash` [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line.

Comment: thanks and where is the next npath getting added to the array for later use? `bazel_cov_req+=(//$npath)`. or you assumed i would do that atleast?

Comment: @AhmFM, yes, I assumed that you would do whatever you wanted with the path once it had been found.  The code only covers your stated "find a file `BAZEL.build` in this entire path in reverse order and stop as soon as it is found in reverse order" requirement.

Comment: This is awesome. I tested your code and serves my purpose. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

With `find` and its `print '%d'` (depth) action:

```
var=$(find "$root_dir" -type f -name "$bbf" -printf '%d\t%p\n' | sort -nrk1 |
  head -n1 | cut -f2-)
```

The `-printf '%d\t%p\n'` action of `find` prints the depth (`%d`) and path (`%p`) of all found files (`-type f`) with name `"$bbf"` (`-name "$bbf"`) starting from `"$root_dir"`.

We then pipe the output to `sort` to sort it numerically (`-n`), in reverse order (`-r`) using only the first field (`-k1`), that is, the depth.

The output is itself piped to `head -n1` that retains only the first line (the first deepest found file).

Finally, `cut -f-2` removes the leading depth and tab.

Note that if you have exotic file names with newline characters in them this will not work. In this case prefer:

```
var=$(find "$root_dir" -type f -name "$bbf" -printf '%d\t%p\0' | sort -znrk1 |
  head -zn1 | cut -zf2-)
```

`-printf '%d\t%p\0'` terminates each output line with a NUL character instead of a newline and the `-z` option of `sort`, `head` and `cut` sets the line delimiter to NUL, not newline. NUL is the only character that cannot be part of a path. So using it as the line separator of each command guarantees that they will see each path as one single line, even if it contains newline characters.

Comment: Can you please explain the options? Especially am interested in how are you stopping on first hit on reverse search?

Comment: It is not stopping, it outputs all found files, preceded by their depth. It is `sort` and `head` that retain only the deepest. `cut` keeps only the path. To better understand how it works you can try it piece by piece: first the `find` command, then `find` and `sort`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Split and traverse backwards:

```
function find_build_bazel_rev {
    local IFS=/ i t=$-
    set -f
    set -- $1
    [[ $t == *f* ]] || set +f

    for (( i = $#; i; --i )); do
        __=${*:1:i}/BUILD.bazel
        [[ -e $__ ]] && return 0
    done

    __=
    return 1
}

find_build_bazel_rev src/services/team && \
    printf '%s\n' "Found: $__"
```

Comment: Thanks @konsolebox. I will try this as time permits but accepted solution that was mapping to my code more and was answered first.